# Could not start AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-11, vt-x

I install the latest version of Android Studio Android Studio 4.0.1.then after i open Android studio and create sample project.after that i open AVD manager and "create virtual device",then after i download Android 10.0+ API 30 level emulator. Issue is AVD not start.please check Images

PC configuration:

Window 7 Professional,Service Pack 1,
8GB RAM,64-bit,intel core i3,Asus

[image: AVD Manager]

[image: Vertual Device Configuration]
I already enable VT- x in my pc

Comment: Add your PC specifications.

Comment: Please first confirm that VT-x is enabled in your BIOS. You might have forgotten to save.

Comment: I have already save.My PC BIOS option displayed as VT-d. @rayalois22

Comment: In your BIOS, do you also have an option called Intel Virtualization or Intel VT. If so, please ensure that it is enabled. Some BIOS utilities have Intel VT instead of the VT-x. Note: VT-d is not equivalent to VT-x.

Comment: Make sure you can start AVDs for other api levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made VT-x enabled and saved it many times,but AVD did not start.
I changed lithium battery on MB,so now AVD works.

I think if lithium battery on MB is low,BIOS will not work properly.

Comment: Solve after confirm that VT-x is enabled in your BIOS.

Answer (score 3):

I did this and it solved my problem:

1. Go to SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> remove "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer)"
2. Click OK to uninstall HAXM.
3. When the uninstall process is complete, close SDK Manager, open it again and install HAXM again the same way.
4. Optional: Wipe data of your emulator and perform a cold boot.
5. If the problem still exists uninstall/install Android emulator in SDK Manager -> SDK Tools as well.

If your system has low resources (RAM, CPU) like mine, it just can't. Don't push it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to reinstalling HAXM, I added android SDK , JDK & JRE paths in environment variable and I got AVD working.

Add new entry user variables in environment variables where

variable name= ANDROID_HOME
value= C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

variable name= JAVA_HOME
value= C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11

variable name= JRE_HOME
value= C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291

Add new entries/apend ANDROID_HOME;JAVA_HOME;JRE_HOME to path user variable in environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

**It might be the issue with HAXM**. To resolve this issue first install HAXM in AVD creation part. If it is showing installation failed then we should **manually install it into the system**.

For that, go to the Intel website, **download the HAXM installer that they provide** (instead of using the one downloaded through Android Studio).

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/tag/v7.6.1

After installing HAXM **enable intel virtualization support in your BIOS**. By default virtualization will be disabled. You can use the following link to enable virtualization in your BIOS.

https://bce.berkeley.edu/enabling-virtualization-in-your-pc-bios.html